# What does "tick" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Let me show you what makes life at this resort tick.

It's an introductory video that shows the behind the scenes of a resort. All the definitions I found from dictionary.cambridge.org don't fit in this context. What does "tick" mean in this context?

Comment: I think it might be more clear if reworded as: _Let me show you what makes life tick at this resort._

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what+makes+tick

Comment: You can replace it with _"go"_

Comment: The answers all say "clock", so now I'm afraid to post my answer, but I'm pretty sure it's not a clock. It's a heartbeat.

Comment: @MrLister - I think that might be another valid interpretation, but I don’t think “clock" is wrong.

Comment: @MrLister clockwork imagery is often used as a metaphor for the heart/heartbeat or other indication of life, so it isn't even a contradictory interpretation. I think it is exactly how it is being used here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an extension of the onomatopoeic meaning of *tick*, as in the sound a clock makes: *tick-tock*. What makes someone or something *tick* is what makes them function, except this is generally even more metaphorical than just the *tick* being a metaphor. If you "know what makes Jeff tick", then you know how his mind works, how he will act, how to provoke him into doing what you want him to do, how to do things he will appreciate, and so on.

Essentially, **it's a set phrase** - "*what makes ... tick*". It refers to **a deep and fundamental knowledge about how "..." works**.

There are variations that go in different directions, of course. As fred2 noted in their answer, to "*really* make something tick" can be to make it work better, faster, more effectively. But to find out what "really makes someone/something tick" can be that, or can be a suggestion that a person has put on a false front and you're going to try to see "behind the mask", so to speak.

If something is "ticking over nicely", that's most directly a reference to an engine or other machine *ticking over*, which means running on idle - not doing anything in particular, but running. It's unclear exactly how we got that expression, whether it also comes from the noise of a clock, but I suspect so. Using that reference means something is functioning and continuing to function without any particular intervention. If it is "just about ticking over" it is barely continuing to function.

Comment: I have a personal theory that it's a metaphor from watches and timepieces-- "What makes a watch tick?" meaning, how does it work, internally, which you can't see? What are the pieces that work together making the ticking sound?

Comment: That's the metaphor I was alluding to, yes.

Comment: I find its use here a bit off, though. If one were talking about what it takes to keep a resort running, it would fit, but it sounds like it's just talking about the main attractions of the resort.

Comment: @Accumulation: Well, I didn't say the writer used it well... but given that it's said to be "behind the scenes" at the resort, I'd say it is about what it takes to keep it running. At least, given the words and that description of the context, that seems most likely.

Comment: It is also possible to refer to a person as "ticking over nicely", meaning that they are getting on with the job without needing intervention. I suppose because it crosses the bridge between a person and object, as the person is behaving *machine-like* (clock-like).

Comment: I disagree with this answer, or at least its phrasing. What makes one tick does not refer to inner knowledge on how one functions. It implies motivation, particularly in its literal sense of what is the force that 'moves' things, or brings them into being / alive; hence the allusion to the clock: what is the very thing that moves the clockhand to 'tick'.
Ref: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/what--makes--one--tick

Comment: @Tasos I think that's another way of expressing the same idea

Comment: Certainly, "what makes X tick" means "how X works" or perhaps "what drives X". But the "deep and fundamental knowledge" isn't implicit in the phrase: consider for example "I have no idea what makes X tick".

Comment: @Michael Kay, I'd say that meant they were nowhere near having that knowledge. However, the strength of the statement may be a matter of interpretation - the strength of many expressions varies with dialect.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common idiom, but checking Cambridge Dictionary, I can appreciate why you couldn't find it.

There are various idiomatic phrasal verbs that this usage is related to.

> Things are ticking along.
>
> The business is ticking over.

Both arise from the metaphor of an engine idling - 'ticking over', but not doing anything much. It also relates to the ticking of a clock as a metaphor for being 'alive', 'working', 'healthy'.

So

> To *really* make something tick.

Has a a more positive sense of 'vibrant', 'lively'.

So the meaning of your sentence is:

> Let me show you what makes life a this resort so lively.

Comment: I'd agree more if the quote in the question had the word *really*. Hard to tell exactly what sense is meant by the quote without more context, I suppose.

Comment: I think you're probably right that the writer *intended* the sense of *what makes it **lively***. But to my mind it's a bad choice of metaphor, given that we normally only use ***tick*** to mean *function smoothly and quietly, at some low "standby" level (**tick over**)* OR *function as an "integrated whole", with a comprehensible mechanism of interlocking gears (**what makes him tick**)* - where in the second sense the gear cogs metaphorically represent something like "motivations”. He might have been better advised to use metaphoric ***hum*** or similar.

Answer (score 4):

The metaphor is a clock. To understand what makes a clock tick is to understand how a clock works, springs, cogs and so forth.

To understand what makes a person tick is to understand their motivations, the way they think, their biases and fears, and so forth.

To understand what makes "life at this resort tick" means to understand the things that make the events which constitute the "life" of the resort happen.

That may not necessarily mean the mechanical things like food, janitors, maids changing towels, but might mean what underlies the social events, or personal intrigue, or whatever constitutes the "life" of the resort, which is a metaphor in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the *tick* with any of the following words:

- work
- thrive
- move
- succeed
- survive

based on the circumstances.